# How to check div has script?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like that:

```
<div class="mydiv">
       <script>
           //my script
       </script>
</div>
```

I want now check `mydiv` class has script or not. How can I do this with Jquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

first go yo div with class `.mydiv` then find `script` then check its `length`

```
   if(  $(".mydiv").find("script").length)
     {    
       alert("exist");
     }
```

Comment: welcome @happi its my pleasure

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) with div. Using `length` with selector will show how many `script` (`tag`) element found in the container that is div with class `mydiv`

```
if($('.mydiv script').length)
{
   //script tag found
}
```

**Description:** Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
$(function(){
  if($('.mydiv').children('script').length>0){
    // have script tab.
  }
});
```